# Visual C#, How to display a `Unicode Character` in a label?

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode

I have a `Label` and I want it to display a musical note.
This [Note](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d163/index.htm).

The problem is, I dont have any of the fonts that can display this note.
The fonts with support are `LastResort` `Quivira` and `Symbola`.

How can I display this character and make it so the compiled program will be able to display this character on another computer?

Comment: You need to get the fonts, license them for distribution and distribute them with your application. I would check first if there are any free open source fonts that can show this glyph.

Comment: What is the UI technology? WPF? WinForms? A browser?

Comment: It is not possible to select custom fonts in winforms afaik

Comment: You can get custom font support from the PrivateFontCollection class.  But the buck stops if you can't get your hands on the font.  Graphics.DrawImage() will of course always work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what UI framework you're using (WPF? WinForms? Browser?), but could you use Graphics Software to make a PNG or GIF of the note and display it that way? If you include the image as an Embedded Resource it would be easy to deploy with you're app.

I also see from your link the image is available in [SVG](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d163/musical_symbol_sixtyfourth_note.svg) format. There are libraries available for rendering SVG in [WPF](http://svg2xaml.codeplex.com/) and [WinForms](http://svg.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Read that as 'bpm' for a moment... ;-)